# $f$ measurable and bounded over a set of finite measure is integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I came across a theorem that states that if $f$ is a bounded function defined on a measurable set $E$ with finite measure, then $f$ is measurable if and only if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I was wondering how can we show the forward implication, i.e if $f$ is measurable then it is integrable.

Comment: Since $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, the set $\{x\in E: f(x) \in I\}$ is measurable for any interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  You can chop up the finite interval $[f_{min}, f_{max}]$ into $n$ disjoint subintervals $I_1, ... I_n$, each of size $\delta = (f_{max}-f_{min})/n$. Then $$f_{min}\mu(E)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}(f_{min}+(i-1)\delta)\cdot\mu(f^{-1}(I_i))\leq f_{max}\mu(E)$$

Comment: The opposite direction seems to depend on your particular definition of "Lebesgue integrable." Sometimes measurability is part of that definition. On the other hand, any (possibly nonmeasurable) function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ has a well defined finite value of $$\sup\left\{\int_0^1s(x)dx : 0\leq s(x)\leq f(x) \quad \forall x \in [0,1],  \mbox{$s$ simple}\right\}$$

Comment: @Michael should $f_{min}\mu(E) \geq 0$ or this is not necessary?

Comment: That holds if $f_{min}$ is nonnegative, but does not hold in general, such as when $f$ can take negative values.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if $f$ is bounded then we can only say that $|f(x)| \leq M$, it coud take negative values in principle. How is the proof valid in that case?

Comment: Where do you see a problem when $f$ can take negative values? If $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$ then we can use $f_{min}=-M$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!